# What are the differences between GeoCityLite.dat and GeoIP2 City?

Tags: geolocation

I have been using GeoCityLite.dat for quite a while and would like to upgrade to a membership account to the new GeoIP2 databases.

Will I need to use different APIs to do that?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The free service GeoCityLite.dat has an accuracy of 95% and GeoIP2 databases is a web service by maxmind, a paid upgrade has higher accuracy an supports REST.

More info at http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/whats-new-in-geoip2/